# Error: Can't take log of -9.4351e+0.007

Tags: perl, logarithm

I am creating a mini search engine using Perl.While doing so I am using a formula with log to the base 10. However for some value I am getting an error:

Can't take log of -9.4351e+0.007.

It is impossible to track where I am getting this error from. I just want to ignore this case. How can this be handled in Perl. Subroutine for finding log to the base 10 is like this:

```
sub log10 {
my $n=shift;
return log($n)/log(10);
}
```

So probably i am looking for a check which says if so and so value dont find log.

Comment: It's not impossible to find the cause, and it indicates a bug in your algorithm.  You should fix the error, rather than putting in a kludge to swallow it.

Comment: If I write `print log '-9.4351e+0.007'` I get "Argument "-9.4351e+0.007" isn't numeric". What is really going on here, and what is the true value of the parameter?

Comment: `perl -MScalar::Util -e 'print Scalar::Util::looks_like_number( q(-9.4351e+0.007) ), "\n"'` outputs `0` (false).  You can't take a log of something that's not a number.  Your problem is in the exponent.  Exponential notation isn't designed with floating point exponents in mind.  See perldoc perlnumber.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot take the log of negative numbers.

See [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html) for more details.

Comment: It isn't a negative number as Perl numbers can't have an exponent of 0.007 - it's simply a string. If you `print -9.4351e+0.007` it will do `print -9.4351e+0 . 007` and the output will be the concatenation of `-9.4351` and '7'.

Comment: @Borodin `print 0+"-9.4351e+0.007"` shows how it numifies, which is as `-9.4351`, which is a negative number :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the value being negative, the string `-9.4351e+0.007` is not a valid number as the exponent part of a floating-point constant can be only an integer.

You must be passing strings to your `log10` function as Perl would not complain about a number in this format.

You need to look at the source of these values as something is going wrong before your function is called, and it will probably give you incorrect results even for those values that can be passed to `log` without error.

Answer (score 1):

"`ln y`" means "find the `x` where `ex` equals `y`".

`e` is a positive number (near 2.17828), so no matter how many times you multiply `e` with itself, you'll never get a negative number.

You cannot find the log of negative numbers.

---

As Borodin also points out that `-9.4351e+0.007` isn't recognized as a number by Perl.

```
>perl -wE"say 0+'-9.4351e+0.007'"
Argument "-9.4351e+0.007" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
-9.4351
```

Comment: ...since we're not considering complex numbers here.